# how to create generic hashmap in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, hashmap

How can I create a generic hashmap in vc++? I am using visual studio and vc++ as language option. I want to seperate my implementation into header(interface) and cpp files. 
header:

```
template<class T1,class T2>
class Generic
{
  map<T1,T2> m1;

  public:

  // Standard constructors and destructors
  // -------------------------------------
     Generic ();
     virtual ~Generic ();

  // Copy constructor and equal operator
  // -----------------------------------
  Generic (Generic &);
  Generic& operator=(Generic&);

  void insert(const T1& key,const T2& value);
  T2 lookup(const T1&key);


};
```

and my cpp file:

```
MyGeneric::Generic()
{
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Generic : destructor
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Generic::~Generic()
{
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Generic : copy constructor
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Generic::Generic(Generic& original)
{
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Generic : equal operator
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Generic& Generic::operator=(Generic& original)
{
  return *this;
}
void Generic::insert(const T1& key,const T2& value)
{
}
T2 Generic::lookup(const T1&key)
{
}
```

I am wondering whether I am making a mistake here. I am also being confused about its usage becuase I am not defining the template in my cpp file. Is that the problem?. How can I delete a single value for a corresponding key in hashmap?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::hash_map` or `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: @Cody, can we use them generically, i mean i need a single map object that can store any kind of key values in it. just based on key and its type i need to retrieve value of type that is binded to that key..if i wont use this logic, my program goes undoubtedly messy..

Comment: @user1061293: Both are template based generic standard library containers,You are essentially trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Apart from all other comments, there is one more basic c++ concept that you need to accept: "You cannot separate the definition of your templates class from its declaration and put it inside a .cpp file". http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12

Comment: If you are seriously interested in writing clean and generic C++ components, get a copy of _C++ Templates: The complete guide_ by Vandevoorde and Josuttis. Your code has several flaws, syntactically as well as conceptually.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need a *variant* type. Have a look at the [boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/variant.html). It allows you to store and retrieve any type you want. You can of course use it in combination with sequences or maps like `std::unordered_map`.

Implementing it your own is quite messy itself. Believe me, I tried :)

Comment: I concur. Implementing a variant type yourself is exceedingly unpleasant.

Comment: @all, Do we have anything like this in c++:
var j;
j=10;
j="Student";
j=new MyClass;
Is there any generic variable in c++ like this?

Comment: In my answer, I posted a link to the Boost library **variant**. It provides the functionality you require. And no, there is no type safe *built-in* way to do this in C++.

Comment: but it has different ways of using in different operating system.. I am using VC++ in windows and the same code is will run on unix machine at at time..how can this work?